# Ansible dynamic inventory script does not get evaluated

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a custom python script that generates an inventory compatible with Ansible:

```py
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("main.log", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{sys.argv}\n")

    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, prog=__file__)
...
```

When I run it manually, everything is fine:

```
python scripts/main.py --list
```

The main.log file gets appended with a new line:

```
['scripts/main.py', '--list']
```

my `ansible.cfg` has the script plugin enabled:

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = script
```

However, when I try to use the script with ansible-inventory, it fails:

```
ansible-inventory -i scripts/main.py --list -vvvv
ansible-inventory [core 2.13.2]
  config file = /Users/jaep/code/ic/pocs/poc_ansible_dynamic_inventory/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/jaep/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/6.2.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/jaep/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible-inventory
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Aug 11 2022, 13:36:31) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /Users/jaep/code/ic/pocs/poc_ansible_dynamic_inventory/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
script declined parsing /Users/jaep/code/ic/pocs/poc_ansible_dynamic_inventory/scripts/main.py as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]: Unable to parse
/Users/jaep/code/ic/pocs/poc_ansible_dynamic_inventory/scripts/main.py as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

What's really surprising is that the script does not get called by ansible-inventory because the main.log remains empty.

Comment: Ansible [checks the shebang](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.13.5/lib/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py#L69), so ensure you have one, and that it is as ansible wishes, or (of course) ensure the file is executable

Comment: @mdaniel please add this as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply forgot to put the correct shebang at the top of the script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and grant execute right to the script:

```
chmod +x scripts/main.py
```